# How can I pull quantity from a DB and multiply it to get the total

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a dropdownlist with a few different games in it, I need to get the item chosen from the dropdownlist, look up the quantity in the same DB, and multiply these together and print the total in the price textbox, how do I get this to work? my HTML is...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" GroupName="Contact" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="198px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
            </asp:DropDownList>

    &nbsp &nbsp<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Quantity:" 
        Width="80px" BorderWidth = "0px"></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="Quantity is a required field.">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" Display="Dynamic"
        ErrorMessage="Quantity must range from 1 to 10." 
        MaximumValue="500" MinimumValue="1" Type="Integer">
    </asp:RangeValidator><br /><br />

    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Total:" 
        Width="80px" BorderWidth = "0px"></asp:Label>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="80px" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

and here is the code I have behind it....

```
 protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from price where" +
        ddlProducts.SelectedValue + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (txtQuantity.Text.Length > 0 && txtQuantity.Text.Length > 0)
        {

        float price = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);

        float sum = price * quantity;
        return sum;

        strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not call return in your TextBox2_TextChanged method but instead, set the value to your HTML control:

```
TextBox2.Text = sum;
```

Also notice that your TextBox2_TextChanged is fired when you press ENTER in your textbox, but you might not want this event... I guess you want to move all that code from inside TextBox2_TextChanged into a new DropDownList_ddlProducts change event.